# Qt Pass Values between 2 Froms

Tags: c++, qt

I haveing 2 FORMS in my Qt Project, the SplashForm and the MainForm!
The SplashForm start's first and when the user presses the button 'Connect' then the MainForm opened! 
In SplashForm, i have some comboBoxes with values which user can choose,
my problem is that I want to pass those values from SlashForm comboBoxes that users have chosen to MainForm class and save them in private members of class, and then show them in MainForm in labels.

So far I can't find anything useful about how to pass values from forms and classes with Qt.
I have tried the Signal/Slot example but I didn't work.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You need to learn C++ basics. Also note that values are passed between **objects**, not between **classes**. A class in C++ is a **user defined type** or **data structure**. And Instances of these data types are known as **objects**. A **form** is just a kind of object.

Comment: *I have tried the Signal/Slot example but I didn't work.* - I suggest showing your code in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else we can only guess as to what the problem is.

Comment: Vladimir Bershov, my problem is not how to pass values between objects, but how to do it right with Qt Signal/Slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In event handler for 'Connect' button, open MainForm after assigning combobox value to SplashForm.

With 
`connect(m_button, SIGNAL (released()),this, SLOT (handleButton()));`,

```
void SplashForm::handleButton()
{
    MainForm* popup = new MainForm(this);
    popup->setLabel(m_comboBox->currentText());
    popup->show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if this is the right way to do it, but it's actually worked for me!